# How to use Humanoid Model : Animator(property) in scripts using Unity Scriptable API

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, game-development

I'm newbie at unity animations and stuff and I want to create a game scene in which at run time I would be able to move a humanoid 3D model and save the movement as an animation (.anim) file. 
I may move the parts of the model by mouse or by mapping scrolling bars to animation property values, somehow.

To do all this I decided to go for the animators (properties) of a model. Kindly look at the picture in the link below to know exactly what I am talking about. (Wasn't able to post image since I'm new to stack overflow too)

[image: Animation window]

I searched the unity Scriptable API for this but wasn't able to find the documentation on how to use the above mentioned property directly in your scripts so that animation curves can be generated from them.

Is it possible to do this? 
Is there a better way to record animations of humanoid models at runtime (in-game mode)  or a better property for humanoid models to use?

Note: The whole animation process is to be handled through code.